# Two "expressions" one of them isn't a statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

1. $((A_1)) \rightarrow (A_2)$
2. $((A_1) \rightarrow (A_2)) \rightarrow (A_3)$

My book says that 1 isn't a statement because:

The first symbol is $($. By counting the number of parenthesis, the "main place" is the sixth symbol (Which is the first place where our sum is $0$ if $($ adds one and $)$ subtracts one.  which is: $\rightarrow$). This symbol is separating two expressions in the form $( \alpha )$ and thus we can split it into:
[image]

The left expression $(A_1)$ is starting with $($, but the "weight" is $0$ only at the last parenthesis and thus 1 is not a statement. (Weight = we start counting '(' adds one to the sum and ')' subtracts one)

However, when we prove that 2 is a statement we say that we need to split it by the tenth place (second $\rightarrow$) into:

[image]

But I don't get it, why is $(A_3)$ can be just $A_3$ but when we had the $(A_1)$ above (first picture) it didn't become just $A_1$ ...

Why is that? I really don't get it... Thanks for helping!

Comment: Could you give some definitions? How is a statement defined?

Comment: @Darsen 1) each "atom" (letter) is a statement. 2) if $\alpha, \beta$ are statements , so are $ \neg \alpha$ and $( \alpha) \rightarrow ( \beta)$. 3) Each statement is a word that is built using 1+2

Comment: And a word is a finite series of these symbols: $\{ (, ) , \neg, \rightarrow, A_i \}$ where $i=1,2,3, \dots$ (They are the atoms of our statements, the letter such as $(A_1) \rightarrow (A_2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When splitting your statements you're undoing the possible construction that led to that statement, i.e., splitting $(\alpha)\to(\beta)$ gives you $(\alpha)$ and $(\beta)$, from which you take $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as statements. Note that we removed $\textit{one occurrence}$ of the parentheses (the only one we can see there really).

In the first case you see that splitting the statement gives you $((A_1))$, which results in $(A_1)$ being a statement, since we just have to remove $\textit{one occurrence}$ of the parentheses. This is false, since $(A_1)$ comes from adding parenthesis to an atom, and that's not valid. Think that inside the first occurrence of a parenthesis there has to be a statement, and that's not the case.

In your second case splitting the statement gives you $(A_3)$, which results in $A_3$ being a statement, and there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 3):

Your rules say that if $p$ and $q$ are statements, then so is $(p)\to(q)$, but nowhere do they say or imply that $(p)$ is a statement. They also say that the atoms $A_i$ are statements. Thus, using the rules you can form a statement $(A_1)\to(A_2)$; call that statement $p$. You can then go on and form a statement $(p)\to(A_3)$, which in full is $((A_1)\to(A_2))\to(A_3)$. But you cannot form $((A_1))\to(A_2)$. That would be justifiable only if $(A_1)$ and $A_2$ were both statements, and while $A_2$ is a statement, $(A_1)$ is not.

In short, you can have $(A_i)$, but only as a component of a compound statement involving $\to$.

Comment: Is it a "universal" rule that the length of a statement mod $3$ is equal to $1$ ? and thus $(A)$ is not possible?

Comment: @CSchofx: That’s clearly not the case, since $\neg A_1$ is a statement of length $2$. Length *per se* has nothing to do with it: it’s a matter of what internal structure your rules of formation allow. The **only** parentheses that they allow are the ones placed around each of two statements connected by $\to$.

Comment: But according to the book only $\neg (A_1)$ is a statement, not $\neg A_1$ and the length of the first one is 4 and the latter is 2 (I've seen the mistake in my comments above, I am sorry)

Comment: @CSchofx: In that case your first comment to **Darsen** isn’t quite right: it should have said that $\neg(\alpha)$ is a statement, not that $\neg\alpha$ is one. And yes, in that case the length of every statement will be congruent to $1$ mod $3$. (I was going by that statement, since I don’t know what book you’re using and probably don’t have access to it anyway.)

Comment: @CSchofx No, that is **definitely not a universal rule**, in fact I find it quite strange. Often, parentheses for disambiguation are not even captured in grammars since terms of that grammars are thought of as trees anyway. The need for such parentheses only arises when reading from or writing down a *linearized* text notation, which is nothing else than representing an actual tree. Hence, one often just gives a grammar and all text notations & parentheses one mentions are syntactic sugar for the trees anyway. Thus, `a = (a) = ((a)) = (((a)))` are all valid and all represent the same tree.